# AVPlayer (video) + MPMusicPlayerController (music)

Tags: ios, avplayer

is it possible to play an instance of AVPLayer (with a video) and in the same time use an instance of a MPMusicPlayerController to play an iTunes playlist?

I've tried several solution but every time I play the video the audio stops and every time I play the audio the video stops.

I play the AVPlayer with this code

```
AVPlayerItem *new = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:videoAsset];

self.playerItem = new;
[player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
[self.playerItem seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];


[player play];
```

and the MPMusicPlayer with:

```
MPMediaItemCollection *items = (MPMediaItemCollection*) aNotification.object;

MPMusicPlayerController *p = [[MPMusicPlayerController alloc] init];
[p setQueueWithItemCollection:items];
[p play];
```

Comment: Show us your audio session setup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as solution I've used two AVPLayer one for the music and one for the video

Comment: Hey could you elaborate on this? I'm having the same issue